# how to make own Extended Validation certificate to display a green bar

Tags: ssl, https

I am new in HTTPS and SSL usage.

I want to know if i can display a green bar using EV. I have my own ssl cert. Signed by own created CA??

Any help is highly accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EV certificates use the [Certificate Policies X.509 extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.4).  This extension can contain an *object identifier* (OID) referencing a CA's *Certification Practice Statement*.  Browsers may recognise particular OIDs and if they are encountered on a certificate, display a green bar.

Because you are using your own CA, you can issue a certificate containing a [commonly recognised issuer OID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#Extended_Validation_certificate_identification).  However, if browsers check that the policy corresponds to the issuer, this will not work.

Comment: These OIDs are indeed hard-coded in browsers: http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/eab4a81e4457/security/certverifier/ExtendedValidation.cpp